# Best cross browser way to handle exceptions for localstorage set item?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am dealing with IE11, and relatively new versions of firefox and chrome. I want a way to detect if local storage is available, and then when I set an item, if an error occurs, if its a permission issue or user disabled it, or no space or just some other error. Also I want a plain javascript solution, no modernizer please.

So far I check if in an exception if the err.code == 22 or 1014, then in firefox and chrome thats a no more space issue. But how does it work for ie 11?

Thanks

Comment: You can use shim from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage#Compatibility) which fallbacks to cookies if `localStorage` is not supported.

Comment: Ever heard of Modernizr? That is what you should use. https://modernizr.com

Comment: @aliasm2k Read the question. "no modernizer please."

Comment: My bad. Didn't notice that part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to check wheather localstorage is not empty-

```
if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null)
```

Use this to check browser support for storage-

```
if(typeof Storage !== "undefined" || typeof Storage !==void(0))
{
//localstorage is available
}
```